# Single page theme that uses pages for the content

Tags: wp-query, pages, page-template, pre-get-posts

I'm making a one page site. On the page I want to run WP_Query three or four times to pull in those 3-4 pages.

The page looks a bit like this:

```
<div class="row">
 <?php

    $args = array( 'pagename' => 'page-1'); 

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
      get_template_part('content');
    endwhile;
    endif;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>


<div class="row">
 <?php

    $args = array( 'pagename' => 'page-2'); 

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
      get_template_part('content');
    endwhile;
    endif;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <?php

    $args = array( 'pagename' => 'page-3'); 

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
      get_template_part('content');
    endwhile;
    endif;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
```

Of course I'm repeating myself here, and that's a bit of a waste. What I want to do is function-ize this instance of WP_Query. Here's what I've done, but it doesn't seem to return anything at all. It has to be something stupid, but I can't see what it could be (in functions.php):

```
/**
 * Functionize wp_query
 *
 * @since 0.1
 */
function waterstreet_fetch_page( $pagename ){
    $args = array( 'pagename' => $pagename ); 

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
      get_template_part('content');
    endwhile;
    endif;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Then of course, in my template files, I want to be able to just run:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php waterstreet_fetch_page('page-1'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php waterstreet_fetch_page('page-2'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php waterstreet_fetch_page('page-3'); ?>
</div>
```

Advice welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How-to simplify your life

I'd go a fairly simpler route:

- Add a "main/parent" page
- Apply your template there
- Add "child" pages to this main page
- Alter the query to include them

### Code example as plugin for a quick test

Here's an (untested) plugin that modifies the query args to not only reduce it to a single query, but modify the main query, so no performance increase has to be taken.

#### Explanation

I'm not sure how you could retrieve the parent post (current) ID inside the function. I guess you have to set it manually. Anyway: Try it with `get_queried_object_id()` (which will likely not work) or see if you could retrieve it from the `$query` object. You could also attach a second filter to `post_clauses` and just change the arguments in this filter (where `get_queried_object_id()` should already be present - or not).

The nice thing that this function does is to attach the `orderby` value as `menu_order`, so you can make use of what the page post type supports by default. Imo you should always make as much use of what core offers as possible.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#70317) »kaiser« Fetch all child posts */
/**
 * Calls the child pages
 * 
 * @param  object $query
 * @return object $query
 */
function wpse70317_pre_get_posts( $query )
{
    if (
        ! $query->is_home()
        OR ! $query->is_front_page()
        OR ! $query->is_main_query()
        )
    {
        return $query;
    }

    $query->set( 'post_type', 'page' );
    $query->set( 'post_status', 'inherit' );

    // Allow the menu order (meta value) to be used
    // ... and start with 0 and count up
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'menu_order' );

    // Change this to your parent posts ID
    $query->set( 'post_parent', 1 );

    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse70317_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: Clever, kaiser. This sounds like a much better way to go about it. Thanks!

Comment: @saltcod You're welcome - Please add how you did the `post_parent` thing (with an edit). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace page slugs with their IDs, then you can use 'post__in' query parameter and 'page' as the post_type in a single query:

```
<?php

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array(2, 3, 5)); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  get_template_part('content');
endwhile;
endif;

?>
```