# Getting the chosen template when iterating through pages

Tags: get-template-part

Im trying print all the pages on a wordpress site. Im using the following code:

> ```
> $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page');
> $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
>
> if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
>     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
>        get_template_part('content');
>     endwhile;
> endif;
> ```

This works fine, but i want each page to be rendered with the template chosen by the admin in the admin menu. Is it possible to fetch the template name so i can provide it to the get_template_part?

Best regards.

Comment: If the answer has been helpful consider accepting it - if you need more information read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename of the template chosen for pages is saved in a post meta field called `_wp_page_template`, which you can get e.g. like this:

```
$template_filename = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', true );
```

Now you have a file name like `example-template.php`, with it you can determine which template to load, if you named it right, so you could e.g. do:

```
$template_fn_wo_ext = substr( $template_filename, 0, -4 );
```

Which does remove the last four characters, so you get `example-template`, now you could do:

```
$template_fn_parts = explode( '-', $template_fn_wo_ext );
```

Which gives you back an array with the string parts, splited at the `-`, e.g. `$template_fn_wo_ext[0]` contains `example`. So you could use this to load your template like this:

```
get_template_part( $template_fn_wo_ext[0], $template_fn_wo_ext[1] );
```

This should get you an idea and started, but it is just exemplary, so do the fine tuning and fitting it to your needs is likely needed.

Comment: My pleasure, besides you you asked nicely on your last question, that always helps:) @TauSand